# What's the procedure for solving recurrence relations without coefficients?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I've a recurrence relation

$$a_{2n}=(2n-1) a_{2n-2}$$

(intial condition $a_2 = 1$)

which has no coefficients, so I can't follow the standard procedure where I find the roots from which we can set up the general solution and then proceed to find alpha etc.

Is there any procedure, that I don't know of, that you follow when you encounter such a recurrence relation with no coefficients? No examples of this kind is in my book and I've looked on the web as well for answers but none found.

Comment: the issue with this recurrence isn't that it has no coefficients, but that it's non-linear. The coefficient of $a_{2n-2}$ is $(2n-1)$

Comment: also, this sequence is only defined for even $n$ at the moment

Comment: Hint: see what $a_{2n-2}, a_{2n-4}, \cdots$ would be.

Comment: @krey: It *is* linear. But the coefficients are not constant.

Comment: @HansLundmark, I wouldn't say that the differential equation $y(2x)=(2x-1)y'(2x)$ is linear. I'm using the same definition of linear

Comment: That's definitely a linear ODE! If $y_1$ and $y_2$ are solutions, then so is $c_1 y_1 + c_2 y_2$ for any constants $c_1$ and $c_2$. But it has non-constant coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$a_2=1$$
$$a_4=3.1$$
$$a_6=5.3.1$$
$$a_8=7.5.3.1$$
$$...$$
Evaluate the first terms and find a pattern.
$$a_{2n}=(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}$$

Comment: it seems to me that we just take $a_{n-2}$ and muliply with (2+$a_{n-2}$) to get the answer for the next sequence, so $a_{2n} = a_{n-2} * (2+a_{n-2}) $ or maybe my brain is not working..

Comment: The second clause of your disjunction holds. You just traded the initial recurrence for another that is wrong, and didn't get any closer to the solution :(

Comment: i see the pattern and understand why double factorial works, gotta look a bit more into it I suppose. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Since each term depends only the previous term, you can ‘unwind’ it:

$$\begin{align*}
a_{2n}&=(2n-1)a_{2n-2}\\
&=(2n-1)(2n-3)a_{2n-4}\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots\big(2n-(2k-1)\big)a_{2n-2k}&\text{after }k\text{ steps}\\
&\;\vdots\\
&=(2n-1)(2n-3)\ldots(3)a_2&\text{after }n-1\text{ steps}\\
&=\prod_{k=1}^n(2k-1)\\
&=(2n-1)!!
\end{align*}$$

Properly speaking you should then prove by induction that the formula $a_{2n}=(2n-1)!!$ is correct, since the ‘unwinding’ technique is really just a more sophisticated form of pattern spotting: when I write the expression showing the result of $k$ steps, I’m extrapolating the pattern that I see in the first few steps.

If you want to get rid of the double factorial, note that

$$(2n-1)!!=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n)(2n-2)\ldots(2)}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^nn!}\;.$$